# What's wrong with my formula for finding matching parts of text?

Tags: excel, formula

What is wrong with this formula? I've tried the formula differently over and over and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

`=IF(((ISERROR(INDEX(Voids!$B:$B,MATCH("*"&$A5,Voids!$A:$A),"",(INDEX(Voids!B:B,MATCH($A18&"*",Voids!A:A,2) ))`)

I am looking for part matching or semi matching text on one sheet

Comment: Can you give an example what you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want something like this

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&$A5,Voids!$A:$B,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP("*"&$A5,Voids!$A:$B,2,0))`

Using `"*"&$A5` means that the formula needs to match with a value where A5 is at the end, if it can be anywhere switch to `"*"&$A5&"*"`

If you have Excel 2007 or later you can use IFERROR to simplify, i.e.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&$A5,Voids!$A:$B,2,0),"")`